# How to empty the uploaded file list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

I am using the jQuery file upload plugin. Everything is fine, except I am not able to empty the uploaded file list.

I found someone suggested using `$("table#img tbody.files").empty();`. I downloaded the [Basic Plus UI demo](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) to test this solution. It could temporally clear the list, but when I refreshed my page, the file list came back again.

I am wondering whether there is a way to clear the list. Thanks

Comment: Do a jsFiddle and share your code

Comment: Hi martynas, I am using the exactly same code from Basic Plus UI(http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my problem, comment out the following codes in "UploadHandler.php".

```
protected function get_file_objects($iteration_method = 'get_file_object') {
    $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
    if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
        return array();
    }
    return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
        array($this, $iteration_method),
        scandir($upload_dir)
    )));
}
```

By doing this, you won't get any file lists after refreshing the page or running `$("table tbody.files").empty();` manually.